# NHibernate QueryOver "select where true"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I need to select the records the for the logged in user or the the records for all users if the logged in user is the manager.

```
int userId = 1;
bool isManager = true; // or false ;

IQueryOver<Demanda, Demanda> Query1 =
nhibernateSession.QueryOver<Demanda>(() => DemandaAlias)
    .Where(() =>
       (DemandaAlias.userID == userId) ||
       (isManager)
);
```

That would translate to SQL someting like this:

> Select * from Demanda where Demanda.userId=1 or 1=1

How do i white the "constant" parameter ?

Comment: Could you show Demanda class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most usual way is to apply an `if` statement in C#, while **building the query**.

```
var query = nhibernateSession
    .QueryOver<Demanda>(() => DemandaAlias);

var someTestIfShouldApplyThisFilter = ...;

if (someTestIfShouldApplyThisFilter)
{
    query = query.Where(() => (DemandaAlias.ID == userId);
}
```

and later we can consume that reference to get a list *(or apply/not apply other where conditions based on other if statements)*

```
query.List<Demanda>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Radim´s answer is perfect, but I wanted to write less Nhibernate/C# code. Found out that this:

```
IQueryOver<Demanda, Demanda> Query1 =
nhibernateSession.QueryOver<Demanda>(() => DemandaAlias)
    .Where(() =>
       (DemandaAlias.ID == userId) ||
       (isManager==true) //<====
);
```

actually works as required, while this

```
IQueryOver<Demanda, Demanda> Query1 =
    nhibernateSession.QueryOver<Demanda>(() => DemandaAlias)
        .Where(() =>
           (DemandaAlias.ID == userId) ||
           (isManager) //<====
    );
```

Will give you a runtime error.

Comment: May I ask why are you using QueryOver instead of LINQ (Query method)? This would be trivial using it. There may be good reasons, of course.

Comment: Better ask another separated question rather than writing an answer with a question inside it. You may leave your first block code as your own answer to your initial question, and post a new question regarding whether QueryOver needs explicit boolean comparisons or not. (It looks like it needs explicit ones.)

Comment: Regarding your own solution, yes this works, but I personally avoid shifting  logic unrelated to the queried rows from iterative code to SQL. Otherwise you tend to hit sooner query performance troubles.

Comment: Frédéric, agree. Just an exercise on how to use QueryOver. I even checked the generated SQL and its ugly as Nhibernate does not short circuit the conditions on the query.